# use TIdHTTP in Delphi to simulate curl command

Tags: delphi, curl, indy

I am trying to use IdHTTP to equivalence the following curl operation:

```
curl -X POST -F "message=@C:\Users\santon\Desktop\ESM_download\token.txt" "https://esm-db.eu/esmws/eventdata/1/query?eventid=IT-1997-0004&station=CLF&format=ascii" -o RecordFileName.zip
```

The curl command is used to download a file from the server that is then saved on the hard drive as DownloadedFileName.zip. An authorization is required through a token file on the hard drive called token.txt. The path of the token file is specified as a parameter of curl.
The best I could do is the following code:

```
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    Params.AddFormField('message', '@"C:\Users\santon\Desktop\ESM_download\token.txt"');

      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      LHandler:= TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(self);
      LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
      try
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
        IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/eventdata/1/query?eventid=IT-1997-0004&station=CLF&format=ascii',Params);
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
        LHandler.Free;
        Params.Free;
      end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: '+E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

But I keep on getting a HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden error.
Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just call curl from your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading the token file into `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` correctly.

Per the curl documentation:

https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F

> -F, --form <name=content>
>
> (HTTP SMTP IMAP) For HTTP protocol family, this lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. **This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388.**
>
> ...
>
> This enables uploading of binary files etc. **To force the 'content' part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign.** To just get the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that **@ makes a file get attached in the post as a file upload**, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.
>
> ...
>
> Example: send an image to an HTTP server, where 'profile' is the name of the form-field to which the file portrait.jpg will be the input:
>
> curl -F profile=@portrait.jpg https://example.com/upload.cgi
>
> ...

In your code, you are creating a *text field* whose content is the filename itself. You are not creating a *file upload* field whose content is the data from the file.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  LOutFile: TFileStream;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      Params.AddFile('message', 'C:\Users\santon\Desktop\ESM_download\token.txt');

      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;

        LOutFile := TFileStream.Create('<path>\RecordFileName.zip', fmCreate);
        try
          IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/eventdata/1/query?eventid=IT-1997-0004&station=CLF&format=ascii', Params, LOutFile);
        finally
          LOutFile.Free;
        end;
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Super thanks Remy Lebeau!
It works fine with one small change the
AddFile command should have an empty string argument at the end in order to compile:

Params.AddFile('message', 'C:\Users\santon\Desktop\ESM_download\token.txt','');
Stelios

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `AddFile()` has a default value of `''` (`function AddFile(const AFieldName, AFileName: String; const AContentType: string = ''): TIdFormDataField;`), so you should not need to specify that `''` explicitly. If your compiler is requiring that, then you are probably using an older version of Indy thaat does not have that default parameter value, and should upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks again! I am using Indy 10.5.7.

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou that is an old version. The current version is 10.6.2